# Need to type password again installing next apps, after 15 minutes. How to disable?

Tags: ios, install, password

to install 20 apps, i need to type apple id password again & again, if idle to installing the next apps more than 15 minutes

is there a way to disable/bypass/extend the time limit?

Nb. i am using ios 7

Answer (score 1):

No, the only options available are **Immediately** or **After 15 minutes**.

Comment: ah is there really no way to do this or alternative solution? i am really tired to type password again & again, even its only free apps :D

Comment: @grgarside I had to chuckle - this came through review as a low-quality post. I passed it of course. Please feel free to delete this comment ;)

Comment: wow this is low quality post? so this problem is not important? if its helpful please vote up guys. need alternative solution if there any

Comment: There is no alternative solution, as noted in the answer. Tetsujin was referring to the fact that the Ask Different software automatically flags short posts as possibly low-quality to help catch spam and single-sentence "answers" that don't really answer the question presented.